# How does this "killer code" work

Tags: windows, erase

I was reading a article about a database programmer, who after learning he was about to be fired put six lines of code that would delete everything on the company's main computer, costing them millions and putting them out of business.

```
7/30/96
F:
F:\LOGIN\LOGIN 12345
CD \PUBLIC
FIX.EXE /Y F:\*.*
PURGE F:\ /ALL
```

Can someone tell me how this code works and what language it is programmed in? I assume SQL?

Comment: Your assumption is not correct.  It is not sql.

Comment: Well, doesnt really matter if I was right or not. I know nothing about database's.

Comment: Do you have a link to this article? Presumably it concludes with some groundbreaking advice such as "always back up your 'main computer'"?

Comment: Well, it seems like it calls an executable called "login" passing 12345 as an argument, changes directories, invokes "fix.exe" and then a command called "purge".

Comment: http://pipelineandgasjournal.com/costly-insider-security-breaches

Comment: @IprogrammedHAL9000. the plural of *database* is *databases* not *database's*

Comment: Well if it did, In the words of Larry Niven, "Evolution in action"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just some (DOS?) shell commands.  The point of the example isn't how clever the code is.  The exact opposite, actually: apparently anyone with basic knowledge of this company's systems, and a beginner's knowledge of the DOS shell, could have done this.  (Notice in particular that their admin password was "12345".)

The example may as well be made up, and possibly is.

Comment: interesting, 6 simple lines of code that a begginer like me could program costed that guy 2 million and three years in jail. lol.